# Does throwing an exception change its state?

Tags: java, exception

I've run some simple experiments like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        NullPointerException n = new NullPointerException();
        System.out.println(Lists.newArrayList(n.getStackTrace()));
        n.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(Lists.newArrayList(n.getStackTrace()));
        throw n;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(Lists.newArrayList(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
}
```

and get output like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:231)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:231)
[MyTest.main(AbstractScannerTest.java:231)]
[MyTest.main(AbstractScannerTest.java:231)]
[MyTest.main(AbstractScannerTest.java:231)]
```

But I wonder if anything is done to an exception when it is thrown. This is a primarily academic question, though it could be relevant under certain circumstances if an exception were part of an API and may or may not have been thrown when provided to an implementation.

Comment: To get a full stack trace and maybe a bit more information when printing an error you can just do `System.out.println(e);` or `System.out.println("error statement", e);` and it should print the whole stacktrace. Just a heads up.

Comment: `printStackTrace` uses `System.err` not `System.out`. To make your output to look as expected, use `printStacktrace(System.out)`.

Comment: Note that, in Java, the exception stack trace is taken when the exception is created, not when it is thrown.

Comment: you could catch and rethrow an exception once or twice, serializing it to see if anything changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `Throwable` object itself is not modified by the `throw` operation; it is simply passed up the call stack similar to how a method's argument would be.  `Throwable`s are generally designed to be immutable objects and don't have setters, though some support modifying the stack trace so that RPC or similar frameworks can make sure that appropriate error-tracing information is included.  That said, a `Throwable` is an object like any other, and you could write a `Throwable` class that had mutator methods to be called in a `catch` block, though that's not usual.

Comment: Actually, Throwable has several methods that will mutate it.  Most notable would be fillInStackTrace that overwrites the stack trace captured when the Throwable was created.

Comment: You're right, I wrote that badly.  `fillInStackTrace`, as the exception I noted, does make the `Throwable` mutable, but most exception classes have no other mutators, and that method may not actually modify the stack trace if `writableStackTrace` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of anything.  The two key things are

- when the Throwable is created
- when getStackTrace() is called it populates the actual array (until then it is stored off heap)